# touchengine iPhone cocoa touch Google App Engine Communication framework: two-way communication

Tags: iphone, python, google-app-engine

As far as I can understand the [touchengine](http://code.google.com/p/touchengine/) framework supports one-way communication and 'Future Features' section on the project page says that two-way communication is partially done (Creating new data or modifying data on the server from iPhone using plists) but I am unable to confirm status of the feature, i.e whether it's complete.

Can anyone please let me know whether the feature is complete and two-way communication is possible using the framework?
Or is there other iPhone framework for python Google App Engine application which supports two-way communication.